# How to shorter regular expression?

Tags: regex, sed

First off, I'm relatively new to regular expressions: I've built a regex that I'm using with sed that works fine for me, it looks like:
`sed 's/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | info  | tst.33.12.carmen | !: //g'` but I'm pretty sure all the repetitive character occurrences could be simplified. How would I do this?

I want to replace:
`20180630 180212.407107 | info  | tst.33.12.carmen | !:` from a line of text (timestamp in the front could be any numbers, strings behind the first '|' are constant)

Comment: don't know for sure about here but in javascript regex you do `[0-9]{8}` for 8 times ( and \d{8} for 8 digits) .

Comment: Kindly try to add sample of input and sample of output with code tags always so that people who are replying could test the solutions and could get better understanding of question too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 please see updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has put sample of input now so adding this solution.

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9]{8} [0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{6} \| info  \| tst\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.carmen \| \!:$//' Input_file
```

**Test of code's working:**

Let's say following is the Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
20180630 180212.407107 | info  | tst.33.12.carmen | !:
fdfjwhfwifrwvf
vwkdnvkwkvwnvwv
20180630 180212.407107 | info  | tst.33.12.carmen | !:
dwbvwbvwvbb
```

Now after running above code following will be the output then.

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9]{8} [0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{6} \| info  \| tst\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.carmen \| \!:$//'  Input_file

fdfjwhfwifrwvf
vwkdnvkwkvwnvwv

dwbvwbvwvbb
```

---

With `sed`'s `-E` option you could use like following but fair warning that it is opted from your solution and never tested since no samples were produced in your post.

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9]{8} [0-9]{5}.[0-9]{5} | info  | tst.33.12.carmen | !: //g'
```

Comment: I've added the piece I want to replace

Comment: @cerr, sure cool, thanks for adding sample. Could you please check my EDIT answer and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: @cerr, I have added a test Input_file and code's test too in post now, kindly do let me know on same.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about matching the exact format of your prefix, but just want to accept some combination of digits, dots and spaces, you can simplify the first part to:

```
[ .0-9]*
```

The complete `sed` expression then looks like:

```
sed 's/^[ .0-9]*| info  | tst\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.carmen | !:$//' file
```